# Link test results to a release stage or environment in Azure Devops through API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am publishing tests results to Azure Test Plans with the API, and I've managed to link the test results to an Azure Release version, but I have not managed to link the results to an environment (or to a Release stage, since the deployments are release stages).

By sending the following HTTP body to create a Test Run using the [Create Run endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP),

```json
{ 
"name":"Test results",
"automated":true,
"plan":{"id":XXXX},
"pointIds":[AAA, BBB, CCC],
"releaseReference":
 {
  "id": XX,
  "name":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "definitionId":YY,
  "environmentId":ZZZ,
  "environmentName":"zzzzz",
  "environmentDefinitionId":DD
 }
}
```

I only get the following links:

[image]

What data am I missing to have the Release Stage filled in my Test Run? And from which API does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted with the following request body, and it can work as expected. You can reference it to update the request body of your API call.

```json
{
    "name": "<name>",
    "automated": true,
    "iteration": "<iteration>",
    "owner": {
        xxxx
    },
    "plan": {
        "id": "<planId>",
        "name": "<planName>",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/<orgName>/<projName>/_apis/test/Plans/<planId>"
    },
    "releaseUri": "vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/<releaseId>",
    "releaseEnvironmentUri": "vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Environment/<environmentId>",
    "releaseReference": {
        "id": <releaseId>,
        "name": "<releaseName>",
        "environmentId": <environmentId>,
        "environmentName": "vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Environment/<environmentId>",
        "definitionId": <definitionId>,
        "environmentDefinitionId": <environmentDefinitionId>,
        "creationDate": "<creationDate>",
        "environmentCreationDate": "<environmentCreationDate>",
        "attempt": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Based on you answer, I managed to find the most succinct body required to link both the release and the stage:
```
{
 "name": "abcd",
 "automated": true,
 "plan": { "id": XXXX },
 "pointIds": [AA, BB],
 "releaseUri": "vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/<releaseId>",
 "releaseEnvironmentUri": "vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Environment/<environmentId>"
}
```